# GNU Octave Installation Problem

Tags: dependencies, octave, gnu

I experienced compiling problems with a previous installation of octave. I uninstalled it and am trying a re-installation using:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liboctave4 (= 4.2.1-2~octave~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: default-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have looked at many related posts on this site and tried their recommended fixes to no avail. When I attempt to install the dependencies that are missing for the Octave installation (like libcholmod2.1.2 and liboctave4) I get further missing dependency issues and go further and further down the rabbit hole.

Any recommended fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added any extra repositories to your sources? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried running `sudo apt install -f` (standard command to fix missing dependencies automatically)? Please [edit] your question if you can add any useful information.

Comment: Agree, which version of Ubuntu is critical missing information here. If I had to guess, this is a problem with conflicting sources, trying to install the octave package from a PPA built for 14.04 on a system that is actually 16.04, or similar.

Answer (score -2):

If you've upgraded any packages since you installed the OS, that can cause problems when you try to install anything that depends on that package.

The first thing to try is `apt-get install -f octave`. This will make apt try to fix the problem.

If that doesn't work, I would try downgrading whatever dependencies are failing back down to the version that came with your operating system. (This has worked for me in the past.)

To do this, you can use the Synaptic Package Manager. Just use the Package > Force Version.. menu item or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, then select the version marked with your version code name (e.g. "trusty"). This shouldn't break anything, and after all, you can always upgrade the package again.

Alternatively, you could try using `aptitude`. It will try to fix the problem for you. (I have never used it myself, but it's worth a shot.)

Comment: It looks like it is missing two packages though (libcholmod2.1.2, liboctave4 and default-jre-headless). To me that doesn't seem like there are packages which have been upgraded that are causing problems. But, the problem is that when I attempt to install those missing packages I get further dependencie issues. Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: Well, if you have upgraded some packages in the past, that can cause problems when installing other stuff that depends on those packages (because you've got the wrong version installed). But if you can _downgrade_ the ones you've upgraded previously that are causing issues (to the version that came with your system, e.g. "trusty"), that might fix the problem.

Comment: It's not missing any packages, per se—it's just got the wrong version installed already. (The error message is a bit misleading; when it says "not going to be installed" it really means "the wrong one already _is_ installed"!)

Comment: The easiest way to downgrade a package is probably through Synaptic, by using Package > Force Version.

Comment: And who downvoted me, can whoever did it please comment as to why? (This solution has worked for me in the past.)

Comment: @JP1992 you can check whether those packages are actually installed using `apt policy <package-name>`. I downvoted this answer because it should never happen that packages upgraded by routine updates need to be downgraded - that's a rare case that would be caused by installing from external sources afaik (APT is smart enough not to break itself), and should be handled by a high level package manager (`aptitude` is very good at this).

Comment: Using any `force` option in any package manager should only be done as a last resort - `force`-ing stuff can break package management and cause situations where you have to resort to more bad solutions...

Comment: I've heard people mention Aptitude, but can't find it on my system—is it not installed by default? And I have had this problem in the past, and downgrading fixed it—but perhaps it does have to do with my external repositories (AFAIK, only the Bodhi Linux repository for the same version of Ubuntu). It seemed to happen with internal packages, though, not having to do with any external repos. (I'm on 14.04 "Trusty".)

Comment: Also, I believe the "Force Version" just downgrades the package to the version you pick, not the same as `--force` at all.

Comment: (And thanks for being so clear and polite about why you downvoted me, @Zanna.)

Comment: `aptitude` can be installed with `sudo apt install aptitude` (assuming APT is working). It will calculate a solution for you, no need to pick a version and force anything. You may be right about the options in synaptic - I am not sure because I don't use it. You could edit your answer to explain how to do what you suggest in OP's case and that would improve it (even if I don't think it is a good idea, maybe I am wrong and it will work for OP and later I can upvote, but now I am going to sleep :) ).

Comment: @Zanna how could I use aptitude to try the installation. Will it, as you said, calculate a solution automatically without me having to install packages manually? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @JP1992 the first thing to try is `sudo apt install -f` as I commented on your question - please try it and if possible answer my other questions there too by updating your question :)